# Symfony 3 app customizing JSON output

Tags: php, symfony

In my Symfony 3 web app I'm serializing some DB rows into Json as follows:

```
    $doc = $this->get ( 'doctrine' );
    $repo = $doc->getRepository ( 'AppBundle:Customer' );
    $result = $repo->createQueryBuilder ( 'c' )->setMaxResults(25)->getQuery ()->getResult ();

    $encoder = new JsonEncoder ();
    $normalizer = new GetSetMethodNormalizer ();

    $serializer = new Serializer ( array (
             new \AppBundle\DateTimeNormalizer(), $normalizer
    ), array (
            $encoder 
    ) );

    $json = $serializer->serialize ( $result, 'json' );
```

This outputs the desired data, e.g:

```
 {companyname:"Microsoft"}
```

In order to (at least initially) maintain compatibility with a legacy system, I'd like all the Json names to be in uppercase, e.g.

```
 {COMPANYNAME:"Microsoft"}
```

Is the best way to tackle this by approaching from:

1. The Encoder
2. The Normalizer(s)
3. The Serializer
4. Some other way?

Please briefly describe the suggested approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement your custom NameConverter a class that implements the `NameConverterInterface` and pass as second argument to the `GetSetMethodNormalizer`. As Example:

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle;

use Symfony\Component\Serializer\NameConverter\NameConverterInterface;

class ToUppercaseNameConverter implements NameConverterInterface
{

    /**
     * Converts a property name to its normalized value.
     *
     * @param string $propertyName
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function normalize($propertyName)
    {
        return strtoupper($propertyName);
    }

    /**
     * Converts a property name to its denormalized value.
     *
     * @param string $propertyName
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function denormalize($propertyName)
    {

    }
}
?>
```

and use it as follow:

```
$uppercaseConverter = new ToUppercaseNameConverter();
$normalizer = new GetSetMethodNormalizer (null, $uppercaseConverter);
```

You can take a look at the doc [Converting Property Names when Serializing and Deserializing](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#converting-property-names-when-serializing-and-deserializing.)

Hope this help